# Linq group by to create nested listview

Tags: c#, linq, listview

I need to create a nested listview and found [a great article](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html) on how to do it, but my situation is a bit different. I am a linq newbie and need a little help please :)

I need to get my data into a format similar in that article to work (on that link above, search for "Configuring the ListView" and see table right above it).

Here is my data:

```
Format    Movie Name    Price
DVD       Star Wars     12.99
DVD       Star Wars II  13.99
Blue-Ray  Star Wars     15.99
Blue-Ray  Star Wars II  17.99
```

Here is what I have, which isn't really that close, but it is as far as I could get:

```
var MoviesToBuy = from Movie in dtMovieListDetails.AsEnumerable()
                    //join MovieDetails in dtMovieListDetails.AsEnumerable() on (string)Movie["ID"] equals (string)MovieDetails["ID"]
                    group Movie by new
                    {
                        Format = Movie["Format"],
                        Movies = Movie
                    } into grp

                    select new
                    {
                        Format = (string)grp.Key.Format,
                        Movies = grp.Key.Movies
                    };

        MoviesToBuy = MoviesToBuy.OrderBy(p => p.Format);

        lvwAmazonMovieGroup.DataSource = MoviesToBuy.ToList();
        lvwAmazonMovieGroup.DataBind();
```

I have 3 specific issues/questions:

1.) What I have doesn't work. Since my second column in the group equates to all rows, no actual group is created.

2.) Despite prior issue, I am also getting "Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource" error. In this case, the Movies column is being created as a DataRow datatype. Not sure if that is what is creating the problem. Can I cast on that field somehow?

3.) how can I sort on the fields in the movies. I.e. in the end I want the data to be sorted by Format then Movie Name so the nested list view looks like this:

```
Blue-Ray
   Star Wars    12.99
   Star Wars II 13.99

DVD
   Star Wars    15.99
   Star Wars II 17.99
```

Any points are greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Chad

Comment: I was able to address issue 2 by changing the Movie field in the group by clause to: Movies = Movie.Table. So just questions 1 and 3 remain!

Comment: FYI: [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a great (free!) tool for testing/debugging queries, mainly because of it's `Dump()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking you could start with the following, adjusting for the proper variable names and AsEnumerable(), etc.

It orders your movies as you want and puts them in a nested structure as you requested:

```
var moviesToBuy = from movie in dtMovieListDetails
    orderby movie.Format, movie.Price
    group movie by movie.Format into grp
    select new
    {
        Format = grp.Key,
        Movies = grp.Select (g => new { MovieName = g.MovieName, Price = g.Price })
    };
```

[Here's an example program that implements the above query.](http://ideone.com/iUj4F)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var res = from m in movies
          group m by m.Format into grouped
          orderby grouped.Key
          select new
          {
              Format = grouped.Key, 
              Movies = grouped.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.MovieName) 
          };
```

Alternatively

```
var res = from m in movies
          orderby m.MovieName
          group m by m.Format into grouped
          orderby grouped.Key
          select new
          {
              Format = grouped.Key, 
              Movies = grouped.AsEnumerable()
          };
```

Using this seed data:

```
var movies = new[] { 
    new Movie { Format = "DVD", MovieName = "SW1"},
    new Movie { Format = "Blue-ray", MovieName = "SW1"},
    new Movie { Format = "DVD", MovieName = "SW2"},

    new Movie { Format = "Blue-ray", MovieName = "SW2"},

    new Movie { Format = "DVD", MovieName = "RF"}
};
```

Produced:

```
Format: Blue-ray
    Movie: SW1
    Movie: SW2
Format: DVD
    Movie: RF
    Movie: SW1
    Movie: SW2
```

Just for completness, I used this code to generate the previous list

```
foreach (var item in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Format: " + item.Format);

    foreach (var item2 in item.Movies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tMovie: " + item2.MovieName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close I think. But the sub group in this case contains all the rows, not just the ones that match the parent group. I think the inner group needs some sort of .ToLookUp to only get the child rows that match the Format (parent group)???

Comment: The sub-group contains all the rows from each format. Which means: the first sub-group contains 2 rows and the second sub-group contains 3 rows. They are effectively grouped. Check my edited response

Comment: Thanks Jupaol. This might have worked, but with my limited linq, I wasn't able to get it to. I really appreciate your time in helping me though!